# Destination of Export GridView to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I'm trying to export gridview into an excel file..which is working fine..

what I want is for the user to choose for his/her desired location..

here's my code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        objexcelapp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25;

        objexcelapp.Cells[1, 1] = "";
        objexcelapp.Range[objexcelapp.Cells[1, 1], objexcelapp.Cells[1, 3]].Merge();

        Dictionary<int, string> month = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        month.Add(4, "January");
        month.Add(6, "February");
        month.Add(8, "March");
        month.Add(10, "April");
        month.Add(12, "May");
        month.Add(14, "June");
        month.Add(16, "July");
        month.Add(18, "August");
        month.Add(20, "September");
        month.Add(22, "October");
        month.Add(24, "November");
        month.Add(26, "December");
        foreach (var i in month)
        {
            objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key] = i.Value;
            objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key].Font.Bold = true;
            objexcelapp.Range[objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key], objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key+1]].Merge();
            objexcelapp.Range[objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key], objexcelapp.Cells[1, i.Key+1]].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < gridviewID.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {

                objexcelapp.Cells[2, i] = gridviewID.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                objexcelapp.Cells[2, i].Font.Bold = true;

        }
        /*For storing Each row and column value to excel sheet*/
        for (int i = 0; i < gridviewID.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridviewID.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        objexcelapp.Cells[i + 3, j + 1].NumberFormat = "@";
                        objexcelapp.Cells[i + 3, j + 1] = gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objexcelapp.Cells[i + 3, j + 1] = gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Your excel file exported successfully at D:\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
        //I want the user to select a location to save the excel file.
        objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("D:\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
        objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;


    }
```

I am new to this. so please bear with me... thanks in advance

this is a windows form

Comment: Excel has `getSaveAsFilename()`.  Forms has `FolderBrowserDialog`

Comment: I happen to solve the problem using `SaveFileDialog`